# Lock down squid proxy to specific IP addresses

Tags: centos, networking, security, squid, fail2ban

I have an anonymous squid proxy server running and I would like it to drop requests from any non-approved IP.

I've limited access already via acl's in the `squid` config. However, if someone tries to access the proxy they get a default squid page advising access is denied. I'd like to remove that step and just have any requests to the proxy port dropped completely to obfuscate it further.

I have `fail2ban` setup to restrict ssh access. Would this be the best way to go by adding an additional rule for squid or is there a `iptables` command I could use instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport (squidport) -s A,B,C,... -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport (squidport) -j DROP
```

Replace `A,B,C,...` with a comma-separate list of allowed IPs.

The second line is only needed if you don't drop by default (which is highly recommended).

Comment: Perfect thank you. Just had to change ALLOW to ACCEPT and it worked a treat :)

Comment: @popcornuk Ah yeah that always trips me up. Locked myself out of a few remote servers that way.